# css, html show long words

Tags: html, css

i have box in right of page and i need show long words in left side.
My problem is that long words jump after box. I add "word-wrap: break-word;" - but is the same.

Please look sample: http://jsfiddle.net/2dpcA/

```
<style>
.page{
    width: 380px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #146A01;  
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
.box{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: #336699;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="box">Some text</div>
        Lorem ipsum<br/>
        Lorem ipsum small text small tekst small<br/>
        VerylongTextIsHEREVerylongTextIsHEREV               
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: I think you linked the wrong fiddle

Answer (score 2):

from the moment the container has a width bigger than long text's width, will place it where is possible without break it. One possible solution could be to wrap your big text with a span and then use the following css:

```
.page span {
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/s6XjW/4/

Comment: Thanks, but text can be a lot of long words and this option is not good to me. If text is after box, he must show in all page width

Comment: In the structure of your html I can't think something else. Another solution, similar to the above, could be to include all your text in left within a `div` with specific width, like the this example http://jsfiddle.net/s6XjW/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use word-wrap and word-break in combination...

```
.page{
    width: 380px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #146A01;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5-7 */
    word-break: break-all; /* Internet Explorer 8-9 */
}
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8DmP/).

Comment: I don't see how your fiddle provides a solution

Comment: I don't see how it doesn't....? Did you view it in IE? It breaks the long text at the specified width. Isn't that what the OP requested?

Comment: copied in some preformatting stuff which caused the white space. I've updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control of the text that appears on the page?

If yes, then you might try inserting a soft hyphen in the long words. It indicates where an optional word break may occur.

```
aterriblylengthy&shy;longword
```